# How to reload data from a component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have `App.vue` component and its child `ItemsList.vue`.
In `App.vue` I have this:

```
export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        ItemsList
    },
    data() {
        return {
            items_list: [
                getRandomItem(),
                getRandomItem(),
                getRandomItem(),
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The data is an array of randomly generated items of the same structure.
I want to return a new array of newly generated items when clicking a button but as I see, `data()` method is being called only once on start and then return just what was generated at the moment.

How do I rerun this method to return a new dataset?

Comment: You don't really re-run it.  Are you trying to update it?  Data is the initial state of an instance of your component.  You change it through the components setters.

Comment: you may interesting in watch property https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property (or direct set `items_list` when button clicked like @zero298 said)

Answer (score 1):

The `data()` method is called only once when the instance of the component is created.
It's a bit like a lifecycle hook.

You can use a function to generate a new array and replace the `items_list` of the component

```
data () {
  return {
    items_list: []
  }
},
methods {
  newList () {
    this.items_list = [
      getRandomItem(),
      getRandomItem(),
      getRandomItem(),
    ]
  }
},
mounted () {
  this.newList()
}
```

Documentation

- [Component's data function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function)
- [Vuejs - Lifecycle Diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)